# Setting boolean to false with button click, Is there a better way to program this?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I want to know if there is a better way to do the following.

I have 4 buttons:

1st sets all the booleans to false

2, 3 and 4 changes it own boolean to true on click and all others to false.
I have done this with 4 separate functions:

```
resetImage(): void{
this.full = false;
this.page = false;
this.display = false;
}

resetImageZoom(): void{
this.full = false;
this.page = false;
this.display = !this.display;
}

resetImageFull(): void{
this.full  = !this.full;
this.page  = false;
this.display = false;
}

resetImagePage(): void{
this.full  = false;
this.page  = !this.page;
this.display = false;
}
```

Thing to note: display shows/hides a component depend on true or false

full and page update a style binding.

Could this be done with switch statement or passing a paramater??

Comment: `this.full  = !this.fullWidth;` and `this.page  = !this.pageWidth;` - are these possible typos in the question?

Comment: Yeah.. updated now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A switch might be a bit cleaner:

```
function(button: string) {
this.full = false;
this.page = false;
this.display = false;
switch(button){
case "full":
this.full = !this.full;
break;
case "page":
this.page = !this.page;
break;
case "display":
this.display = !this.display;
break;
}
}
```

In your HTML you will need to call the name of the function and pass in the button name:

```
(click)="function('buttonname')"
```